# Align split equation to the margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, line-breaking

How to align a two-lined equation such that the first line left aligns with the surrounding text and the second line right aligns with the surrounding text?

Example (where the pipes denote the left and right edge of the surrounding text):

```
|                       |
P(x) =
    a + b + c + d + e + f
|                       |
```

I fiddled around with `flalign`, `multline`, and `multlined`, but did not get it working the way I want. Prepending a `\vphantom` to the second line allows me to right-align the second line of the equation. Appending a `\vphantom` to the first line does not left-align the first line (the `\vphantom` continues to run in the right margin).

Comment: You could use the environment `multline` provided by the package `amsmath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the environment `multline` provided by the package `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\multlinegap{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
P(x) =  \\
   a + b + c + d + e + f
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

The `\setlength\multlinegap{0pt}` assures no indentation of the first line.

Comment: I think it will have to be `0pt`, not `Opt`, for this to succeed... :-)

Comment: Upps... my mistake! Thank you for the correction

Comment: Thanks. I edited your solution slightly by first storing the original `\multilinegap` value, then set it to zero, then present the equation, and afterwards restore `\multilinegap` back to its original value

Answer (score 4):

Ypu can define the `flmultline` environment and its starred counterpart:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{flmultline}
  {\multlinegap=\z@\start@multline\st@rredfalse}
  {\endmultline}
\newenvironment{flmultline*}
  {\multlinegap=\z@\start@multline\st@rredtrue}
  {\endmultline}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{flmultline*}
P(x)=\\
aaaaa+bbbbb+ccccc+ddddd+eeeee+fffff+ggggg+hhhhh+iiiii
\end{flmultline*}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{flmultline}
P(x)=\\
aaaaa+bbbbb+ccccc+ddddd+eeeee+fffff+ggggg+hhhhh+iiiii
\end{flmultline}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The idea is simple: locally set `\multlinegap` to zero.

[image]

Comment: it's easier `multline` than this.

Comment: @skpblack With this one still has `multline` (with the normal setting of `\multlinegap`) available.